# QT How to wait in a main programm for one thread (without using sleep/freezing)

Tags: c++, qt

My QT-program have 4 steps in a loop:

1. reading n config file
2. transmitting values via UART to uC
3. recording audio files and receiving values from uC
4. stopping recording and writing a header (*.PCM to *.WAV conversion)
5. go to n+1 config file and starting again with step 1.

For audio recording I'm using:

```
m_file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly); //audio access mode initialisation
writeHeader(); //writing header to convert PCM to *.wav
m_audio->start(&m_file); //start recording
QTimer::singleShot((record_time_sec+4)*1000), this, SLOT(StopRecording()));
```

QTimer::singleShot() makes a new thread open and while recording (step 3) is working - the main program is still running and I see that the program try to make direct the next steps in a loop without waiting for stopping recording.

How it is possible to wait for ending of recording threads and then following a next steps?

P.S. I was reading about `QCoreApplication::processEvents()` but I', not sure about, how to use that function!?

---

```
void Measure::processMeas(){

    // Declaration xxxxxxx
    // Read config files 
    QDir directory("tralala");
    QStringList config_files = directory.entryList(QStringList() << "*.txt", QDir::Files);
    config_files_cnt = config_files.count();

    foreach(QString filename, config_files) { //config loop
        Conf *conf = new Conf(directory.absoluteFilePath(filename));
        qDebug() << "Config file: " << filename << " is processed";

    // Error message xxxxxxxx
    // Prepare measure 
        qDebug()<<"Debug: Prepare measure";

        QStringList lines = conf->getConf_lines(); //read all rows of config files

        record_time_100ms = lines.count();
        record_time_sec = record_time_100ms / 10;

        for(i=0; i < (uint32_t)lines.length(); i++){ //prepare single rows of config files

            QString uart;
            QString uart_hex;

                if(i > 5 && i < lines.length()){
                QStringList speed_chunks = lines.at(i).split(","); //split rows by decimal point

                m1 = speed_chunks.at(2).toInt();
                m2 = speed_chunks.at(3).toInt();
                m3 = speed_chunks.at(4).toInt();
                m4 = speed_chunks.at(5).toInt();

                hextest.resize(10);
                hextest[0]=255;
                hextest[1]=m1>>8;
                hextest[2]=m1;
                hextest[3]=m2>>8;
                hextest[4]=m2;
                hextest[5]=m3>>8;
                hextest[6]=m3;
                hextest[7]=m4>>8;
                hextest[8]=m4;
                hextest[9]=238;

                qDebug()<< "Transfer data: " << i << " from " << lines.count()-1 << " rows transmitted";

                m_serial.write(hextest);
                m_serial.waitForBytesWritten(1000);
                QThread::usleep(50000);

                }//if(lines.at(i).contains(",")) end
            }//for end

    // Measurement 
            if(stm==0){
                QString path = SAVE_AUDIO_PATH+QDateTime::currentDateTime().toString("yyyyMMdd_hhmmss");
                m_file.setFileName(path+".log");
                m_audio->StartRecording(path+".wav");
                stm=1;
            }
            qDebug()<<"Measurement takes " << record_time_sec+4 << " seconds";
    // Stop measure 
           measure_cnt++;
           // All configs files done 
            if(measure_cnt>=config_files_cnt){
                //m_timer->stop();
                qDebug()<<"All measure done";
                // qApp->quit();
            }
        }//foreach



}
*************************************************
void Audio::StartRecording(QString rec_file_path)
{
    m_file.setFileName(rec_file_path); //audio recording path format
    m_file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly); //audio access mode initialisation

    writeHeader(); //writing header to convert PCM to *.wav (Step 1)

    m_audio->start(&m_file); //start recording

    QTimer::singleShot((15000), this, SLOT(StopRecording()));
}

//Stop recording

void Audio::StopRecording()
{
    m_audio->stop();
    writeHeaderFinal();
    m_file.close();
}
```

writeHeader(); and writeFinalHeader(); are just functions to convert PCM to *.Wav

I think the big Problem - i try to combine normal code loop with signal-slot principles!? Maybe I have to split my code to different parts and make a slots - and if one part are over, I have to go to next slot? Its a right logic?

Comment: `QTimer::singleShot` does not start a thread. It just schedules the slot to be executed in the next iteration of the main thread's event loop.

Comment: The slot will be executed in the main thread approximately `(record_time_sec+4)*1000 ms` later. There is no additional thread created.

Comment: In general, Qt is (or is best used as) purely event based system. In other words, you never ask "How can I wait...?". The question is always "How do I get a signal or an event when...?". And then you never block in any of your methods, you always do something (quicker the better) and return. Now here, it is unclear what "ending of recording" means here. Is it that timer, or is it something else? Please clarify!

Comment: Extending on what hyde said. You schedule StopRecording() to be called after a certain time. And now you want to start the next recording when that has finished. So replace the StopRecording call with a little function that calls StopRecording and then StartNextRecording. Or have StopRecording emit a ReadyForNextRecording signal and start recrodings when that signal happens (also emit that once at the start to get started).

Comment: @ Nicos C. and drescherjm: thanks, i have a wrong understanding of function! 
@ hyde: thank you also: ending of recording is just a function:  
```void Audio::StopRecording()
{
    m_audio->stop();
    writeHeaderFinal();
    m_file.close();```
@Goswin von Brederlow: yes, thanks, I think I mixed two different principles. I try to describe my program above now!

Comment: To be precise the slot will be executed in the thread in which `m_audio` lives, which does not necessarily has to be the main thread. The code doesn't show how `m_audio` is created or if it is moved to another thread so we can't really tell.

Comment: @danadam hi, sorry, here is a code (m_audio will be created in another class) 
```Audio *m_audio = new Audio();```

Comment: and: //Signal-slot connection to show actual Audio state or errors output
    ```m_audio = new QAudioInput(format, this);
    connect(m_audio, SIGNAL(stateChanged(QAudio::State)), this, SLOT(handleStateChanged(QAudio::State)));```